# Xcode manual integration of OneSignal iOS SDK failing - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OneSignal"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, onesignal

I'm experiencing build issues manually integrating OneSignal into Xcode for my React Native project. Dynamic integration using Cocoapods doesn't work (causes major conflict issues). I've spent hours troubleshooting this with OneSignal support and using online materials but no luck. I've also tried the React Native SDK which doesn't throw an error but doesn't work either. I think I'm almost here but having an issue I have not been able to resolve.

As soon as I add the following code to my AppDelegate.m:

```
[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                         appId:@"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
      handleNotificationAction:nil
                      settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: @false}];
OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayTypeNotification;

[OneSignal promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse:^(BOOL accepted) {
NSLog(@"User accepted notifications: %d", accepted);
```

I get the following error while building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OneSignal", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in 
AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to 
see invocation)
```

I've trawled through Google and StackOverflow for an answer but no luck. It seems almost everyone uses Cocoapods or Carthiage.

I've followed this: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup and having an issue here... https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup#section-4-add-required-code. If I comment out that code it builds fine. Even importing OneSignal.h has no issue.

I've also tried this: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup. This all works as expected provided I follow the "Without Cocoapods" section. When I add the React Native code to my project it all seems to be fine but I don't see the session registered with OneSignal.

Comment: Manually linking didn't work for me, I used cocoapods also.

Comment: I tried to use Cocoapods several times but it kept failing due to conflicts with the React library it was trying to import. The only way I could get this mostly working was by manually adding it to Xcode. The issue is the last step as mentioned above causes the package not to build.

Comment: Did you fixed it ? Got the same

Answer (score -2):

> When I add the React Native code to my project it all seems to be fine
>   but I don't see the session registered with OneSignal.

and

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

From what I see I can assume that you try to run your code on **simulator**

The thing is that **iOS simulator does not support push notifications** (although Android supports it, but for Android it is called Emulator, not simulator, you could google if you want to read more on that)

Since pushes only works for a real device, I would assume that guys from OneSignal does not provide a compiled version for simulator.

If react-native version works fine with a real device, then it works as expected.

Comment: Push notifications don't work on a simulator but it doesn't prevent it from building and deploying. The notifications just don't come through. The issue I am having is that the build is failing totally so not able to deploy onto anything.

Comment: could it build on a real device?

Comment: It is the same on both simulator and real device

Comment: it 99% would be different, if you build for device, x86_64 won't appear, it would be something else.

Comment: I build for a real device and the same build failure...

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OneSignal", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)